If $f(x)=m(x) + \mathcal O\left( e(x)\right)$, then is $f(x)^\ell = m(x)^\ell + \mathcal O\left( e(x)^\ell\right)$?
I am new to advanced calculus and I am a bit confused about the following.
If I know that a function $f$ varies as
$$f(x)=m(x) + \mathcal O\left( e(x)\right)$$
then is it okay to say that
$$\left(f(x)\right)^\ell= \left(m(x)\right)^\ell + \mathcal O\left( \left(e(x)\right)^\ell\right)$$
for any positive integer $\ell$?
If not, then what is an asymptotic form for $f(x)^\ell$ ?
Even if my asymptotic form is correct, then are there better forms known? Please help.
Notice that the problem I am interested in is for the case $x\to \infty$. Also, I am more interested in knowing an asymptotic form of $f(x)^\ell$ than whether the form I suggested is true.

$1 + x = 1 + \mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x \to 0$, but $(1+x)^2 = 1 + 2x + x^2 \neq 1 + \mathcal{O}(x^2)$.

@JeanAbouSamra: that seems wrong. $2x+x^2 \in \mathcal{O}(x^2)$.

What? This is as $x \to 0$, not $x \to \infty$.

@JeanAbouSamra it is $x \to \infty$ though

@nejimban this is an excellent answer! you can post it as an answer if you want to.

@Dumbestpersononearth Thanks. Glad it helped.

I assume that $e(x)/m(x)\to0$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{f(x)}{m(x)}\right)^\ell
&=\left[1+\mathcal O\!\left(\frac{e(x)}{m(x)}\right)\right]^\ell\\[.4em]
&=1+\mathcal O\left(\frac{e(x)}{m(x)}\right)\!.
\end{align*}
This yields
$$\Bigl(f(x)\Bigr)^\ell=\bigl(m(x)\bigr)^\ell+\mathcal O\Bigl(e(x)\bigl(m(x)\bigr)^{\ell-1}\Bigr).$$

This is not quite true. Consider the case $\ell=2$ and $f(x)=m(x)+e^x$. Then we have
$$ f(x)^2 = m(x)^2 + 2 m(x) e^x + (e^x)^2. $$
Now, if it was true that
$$ f(x)^2 = m(x)^2 + O((e^x)^2), $$
then we would have
$$ 2 m(x) e^x + (e^x)^2 = O((e^x)^2), $$
which means
$$ 2 m(x) e^x = O((e^x)^2). $$
Dividing both sides by $2e^x$ we get
$$ m(x) = O(e^x). $$
However, this does not have to be true. Pick for example $m(x)=e^{100x}$.

Please note that what I need more is an asymptotic form for $f(x)^\ell$. Do you have any suggestions for that?

The counterexample I gave in the comments can be adapted to $x → +∞$ instead of $x → 0$. We have $x + 1 \underset{x → +∞}{=} x + \mathcal{O}(1)$, but $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 ≠ x^2 + \mathcal{O}(1)$ because $2x + 1 \neq \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Please note that what I need more is an asymptotic form for $f(x)^\ell$. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Use binomial expansion.
